# How to get list of statically linked libraries into another library

Tags: c++, gcc, build, compilation, linker

I actually have some problem with **huge project**.

I want to check if there is any library linked statically to my shared library.

I have `library.so` file and I want to decrease **as much as possible** its size. I enable optimization in gcc (`-O2`) (btw. I know there is `-Os` flag, but I don't want dramatically slowdown). I stripped this library also.

For now I want to know if there is any statically linked library to my library.so.

I tried `objdump` and `readelf` command, but it shows only which shared libraries is needed by my library.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Static library linked to anything, either executable or shared library is non-distinguishable from basic .o file. There is [mklibs](https://launchpad.net/mklibs) but you need to have static library.a to recreate reduced library.so without unneeded symbols. And as for dramatical slowdown - have you done some performance checks to determine if `-Os` is suitable for you?

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski Not yet, I haven't perform this checking. So you say that I cannot check which libraries is statically linked?

Comment: Well, at first try if size reduction achieved by `-Os` is even suitable for you. If not - do not even bother with performance testing.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski Ok, I will check that ;)

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski Hey, maybe you know if in gcc compilation log with `--verbose` option there should be some information about static linking?

Comment: No idea. But is should be easy to check.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski I tried to find sth, but there is 7k lines of log, and after quick look at it I cannot found anything useful.

Comment: Determining which libraries in the linkage of your `library.so` project
are static and which are dynamic is straightforward but it is unclear
how you think this information will enable you to shrink the size of `library.so`.
Please edit your question to explain *what you will do about it* when
you discover you are linking a static library.